# Tuplas: index out of range - recursão

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão, tuple

Estou com um problema de `index out of range` na minha tupla. O objetivo do código é criar uma função recursiva que encontre um *substring* dentro de uma tupla com elementos de qualquer tipo. Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse erro?

O problema está na chamada recursiva de quando tenho uma tupla dentro de outra tupla. O programa está retornando `index out of range`:

```
def conta(tupla,string):
    if isinstance(tupla[0], list) or isinstance(tupla[0],tuple):
        return conta(tupla[0],string) + conta(tupla[1:],string)
    if(len(tupla)==1):
        if isinstance(tupla[0],str):
            if tupla[0].find(string)>=0:
                return 1

        return 0

    if not isinstance(tupla[0],str):
        return 0 + conta(tupla[1:],string)

    if tupla[0].find(string)>=0:
        return 1 + conta(tupla[1:],string)
    else:
        return 1 + conta(tupla[1:],string)

tupla1=("foi",)
tupla2=([1,2,3],[['onde',2.3], 'oi',78], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
tupla2=([1,2,3],(('onde',2.3), 'oi',78), ['a', 'b', 'c'])
tupla3=([1,2,3],(('onde', 'noiva',2.3), 'oi',78), ['a', 'b', 'c']) 
tupla4=(('MAO', 'MOA') , 13.8 , 'c' , 6 , [2,3]) 

resultado1=conta(tupla1,"oi")
resultado2=conta(tupla2,"oi")
resultado3=conta(tupla3,"oi")
resultado4=conta(tupla4,"oi")

print("\nRetorna ",resultado1,end='')
print("\nRetorna ",resultado2,end='')
print("\nRetorna ",resultado3,end='')
print("\nRetorna ",resultado4,end='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não conseguirei dizer exatamente o que está errado, pois simplesmente não consegui entender a lógica que você implementou. Se você editar a pergunta e comentar seu código, talvez facilite o processo.

De qualquer forma, a função parece ter muita coisa desnecessária para fazer seu propósito. Uma forma mais fácil e rápida de implementar essa função seria:

```
def conta(tupla, string, total = 0):

    if type(tupla) in [list, tuple]:
        for item in tupla:
            total = conta(item, string, total)
    else:
        total += str(tupla).count(string)

    return total
```

Ou seja, se o elemento `tupla` for do tipo `list` ou `tuple`, percorra-o atualizando o valor de `total` para cada item deste objeto. Perceba que é recursivo, então se o elemento da lista for outra lista, funcionará igual. Se o elemento não for uma lista ou tupla, converte-o para *string* e verifica o número de ocorrências de `string` em seu valor, incrementando `total`. No fim, retorne o valor de `total`.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/8ewpz9).

Se você apenas converter a `tupla` para *string* e verificar o número de ocorrências de `string` na mesma funcionará perfeitamente também. Veja um [exemplo](https://ideone.com/u3rJ4l).

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson Woss!